# connecting Esp8266 client to sub-directory of a local web server

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, esp32, arduino-esp8266

I am going to connect Esp8266 client to local web server. Here I am connecting to a sub-directory inside local web server. In a browser It's easy with just typing: 192.168.1.103/public_html/register.php
When it comes to esp8266, I use the following function: client.connect(host, 80). In this function, host can be either an array of IP address or a URL. Giving host a value of 192.168.1.103/public_html/register.php doesn't cause the esp8266 client to connect to the server sub-directory. However it has no problem with connecting to the IP address when I give the host the value of 192.168.1.103 (Server IP). I appreciate if you give me help finding a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WiFiClient of ESP8266WiFi library wraps a TCP socket. A TCP socket connects to IP address and port where a server side socket is created. After the sockets are connected, any data can be send and received over it both ways.

[The HTTP communication protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is an application layer communication protocol usually running over a TCP socket connection. It makes a HTTP server understand the request from a HTTP client and the client to understand the response.

To make HTTP communication, send a valid HTTP request to the server over TCP socket (WiFiClient). Or use HTTPClient to handle the HTTP protocol for you.

Example of HTTP GET request with WiFiClient:

```
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    client.println("GET /public_html/register.php HTTP/1.1");
    client.print("Host: ");
    client.println(server);
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    client.flush();
  }
```